# Global Nav Bar, Moved Position and fill row? How do I do it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css, custom-masterpage

I have been playing around with some CSS to override some MasterPage elements, one of which is to customise the global nav bar. Global Nav is represented using a Managed Meta Data term-set.

This is what it looks like currently:

[image: Before]

using the following code snippet:

```
    /* NEW TOP NAVIGATION BEGIN */
.MenuWrapper {
    background-color:#AFA9A2 !important;

    padding:0px !important; 
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox a.ms-core-listMenu-item {

    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px !important;
    background-color:#AFA9A2 !important;
    margin:0px !important;
    border-right: 0px solid #AFA9A2 !important;
    font-weight:600 !important;
    text-transform:uppercase !important;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation .static {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation .menu-item-text {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 13px !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox a.ms-core-listMenu-item {
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    border-right:1px solid #AFA9A2 !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox a.ms-core-listMenu-item:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #842B91 !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox a.ms-core-listMenu-selected {
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    background-color: #842B91 !important;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation ul.dynamic {
    border:1px solid #AFA9A2 !important;
    background-color:#842B91 !important;
    color:#AFA9A2 !important;
    padding:0px !important; 
    margin-left:10px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
} 

#DeltaTopNavigation  ul.dynamic .menu-item-text {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation ul.dynamic li ul.dynamic {
    margin-left:0px  !important;
} 


.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox ul.dynamic a.ms-core-listMenu-item {
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #AFA9A2 !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox ul.dynamic a.ms-core-listMenu-item:hover {
    background-color:#842B91 !important;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation li.dynamic {
    padding: 0px !important;
    list-style:none !important;
    width:inherit !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation li.dynamic a.ms-core-listMenu-item{
    border-right: 0px #AFA9A2 !important;

}

.ms-breadcrumb-top{
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    top: 55px;
}

/* NEW TOP NAVIGATION END */
```

This is what I would like to get it to look like, but after hours of messing around, still can't get it to work (excuse the badly drawn screenshot!):

[image: AfterTwo]

Ideas and suggestions much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS:

```
div.ms-breadcrumb-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  top: 85px;
}

div#contentRow {
   padding-top: 85px;
}
```

A better way would to be restructure your html in the master page. Move the top nav code block in to it's own div under the header.

Comment: Thank you! - that was very helpful. I really should get my figer out of my *** and finally learn HTML/CSS ! :) - problem now is that while it has aligned itself, it's moved the search box with it and it still has not filled the right-side

Comment: Ok, i just changed the .ms-breadcrumb-box to .ms-breadcrumb-top and the margin-left: -20px !important; to margin-left: -220px !important; and that got it to allign left without moving the search box also. I still cant fill the entire line in color though, hmmm

Comment: i got it!! - so proud of myself, i winged it and put in margin-right: 220px;background-color: #AFA9A2 !important;